# need to print a pattern, got first half. Can't figure out second half

Tags: python, printing

I need to print the following pattern:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Got the first half, but can't figure out how to print the second half

```
for n in range(6):
print("*" * n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a second loop to print the second half:

```
def print_triangle(height: int) -> None:
    for n in range(1, height):
        print('*' * n)
    for n in range(height, 0, -1):
        print('*' * n)

print_triangle(height=5)
```

**Output:**

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```